# Catch style tag inner content

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I use the following regex to catch all style HTML tags and the inner content:

```
<style[^>]*>([^<]+)?<[\s\/]+style>
```

That works well, it catches everything till the closing style tag, but fails if the tag content contains other tags ( e.g. svg, path ) See this example https://regex101.com/r/kEyFED/1

How do avoid that and catch such content too?

Comment: Well, you are explicitly saying `([^<]+)` which translates to "all characters except `<`" ...

Comment: @derpirscher of course it does, I am trying to figure out how to change it.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML, use a DOM parser. You're using that to prevent matching across multiple `<style>` tags, but because of that you can't have any nested tags.

Comment: @Barmar I'm perfectly aware of that, but can't use DOM parser for that.

Comment: You could for isntance use a *lazy quantifier*  `(.+?)` That will match anything up to the next `</style>`

Comment: [This?](https://regex101.com/r/j0TS72/1)

Comment: `<[\s\/]+style>` will match either `< style>` or `</style>`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: BTW, `([^<]+)?` is equivalent to `([^<]*)`.

Comment: @lucas_7_94 Probably not, because if you have something like `<style> .... </style><style> ... </style>` (ie no linebreak between the style blocks) or you specify the `/s` flag it will happily merge those two styles blocks into one match instead of two ... Your expression just seems to work, because `.` in a reguar expression *does not*  match a linebreak if you dont specify the `/s` (singleline) flag

Comment: If lookaheads supported, try like [this](https://regex101.com/r/MdxVP3/1) or [that](https://regex101.com/r/YRJ3Oc/1) (first is more efficient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest

```regex
<style[\w="'\s-]*>(.*?)<\/\s*style>
```

This should match the style tag and put the inner contents of it into the group 1. It matches the least amount of characters between `<style>` and `</style>`. The escaping of `/` depends on the language you use.

UPDATE: I updated my regex to also match the attributes in an element. The elements are not validated in any kind, the stuff is just there to make the style tag match. Still would not match properly, if `>` is contained inside an attribute value.

UPDATE 2: end tag now allows for whitespace between `</` and `style>`.

Comment: Becomes problematic with nested <style> tags - outer <style> matches inner </style>

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Well, that's the price you have to pay if you want to parse nested structures with regular expressions ...

Comment: @ChrisMaurer according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) reference for the `<style>` element, valid HTML must not contain any HTML elements inside, only CSS is allowed there. So this should not be a big problem - except if you want to write an HTML validator.